# Efficient string similarity grouping

Tags: r, string, performance, levenshtein-distance

**Setting**:
I have data  on people, and their parent's names, and I want to find siblings (people with identical parent names).

```
 pdata<-data.frame(parents_name=c("peter pan + marta steward",
                                 "pieter pan + marta steward",
                                 "armin dolgner + jane johanna dough",
                                 "jack jackson + sombody else"))
```

The expected output here would be a column indicating that the first two observations belong to family X, while the third and fourth columns are each in a separate family. E.g:

```
person_id    parents_name                           family_id
1            "peter pan + marta steward",           1
2            "pieter pan + marta steward",          1
3            "armin dolgner + jane johanna dough",  2
4            "jack jackson + sombody else"          3
```

**Current approach**:
I am flexible regarding the distance metric. Currently, I use Levenshtein edit-distance to match obs, allowing for two-character differences. But other variants such as "largest common sub string" would be fine if they run faster.

For smaller subsamples I use `stringdist::stringdist` in a loop or `stringdist::stringdistmatrix`, but this is getting increasingly inefficient as sample size increases.

The matrix version explodes once a certain sample size is used. My terribly inefficient attempt at looping is here:

```
#create data of the same complexity using random last-names
#(4mio obs and ~1-3 kids per parents) 
pdata<-data.frame(parents_name=paste0(rep(c("peter pan + marta ",
                                "pieter pan + marta ",
                                "armin dolgner + jane johanna ",
                                "jack jackson + sombody "),1e6),stringi::stri_rand_strings(4e6, 5)))

for (i in 1:nrow(pdata)) {
  similar_fatersname0<-stringdist::stringdist(pdata$parents_name[i],pdata$parents_name[i:nrow(pdata)],nthread=4)<2
  #[create grouping indicator]
}
```

**My question**: There should be substantial efficiency gains, e.g. because I could stop comparing strings once I found them to sufficiently different in something that is easier to assess, eg. string length, or first word. The string length variant already works and reduces complexity by a factor ~3. But thats by far too little. Any suggestions to reduce computation time are appreciated.

**Remarks**:

- The strings are actually in unicode and not in the Latin alphabet (Devnagari)
- Pre-processing to drop unused characters etc is done

Comment: Your for loop is not working. Also, you should provide example data in the scale you are working...

Comment: I hope you do understand that for confidentiality reasons I can not provide the actual data

Comment: Question: Wouldn't it be better to check `pdata$parents_name[1:i]` for distance? The first item will always be it's own family_id (because no other family id are assigned yet). Then the second item only needs to be compared to the first item because none of the other items have a family_id assigned yet.

Comment: If these examples are close enough to your real case you may not need to compute all pairwise distances, you may consider that 2 strings have the same family_id if the distance between them is less than say 4, and consider the first instance of a family_id to be the canonical instance, if you have a decent amount of instances by family_id it will be much faster. Additional prefiltering on distances worth computing could be done by splitting around " + " and dismissing pairs that have very different length (say more than 3 characters).

Answer (score 11):

**There are two challenges:**

A. The parallel execution of Levenstein distance - instead of a sequential loop

B. The number of comparisons: if our source list has 4 million entries, theoretically we should run 16 trillion of Levenstein distance measures, which is unrealistic, even if we resolve the first challenge.

To make my use of language clear, here are our definitions

- we want to measure the Levenstein distance between expressions.
- every expression has two sections, the parent A full name and the parent B full name which are separated by a plus sign
- the order of the sections matters (i.e. two expressions (1, 2) are identical if Parent A of expression 1 = Parent A of expression 2 and Parent B or expression 1= Parent B of expression 2. Expressions will not be considered identical if Parent A of expression 1 = Parent B of expression 2 and Parent B of expression 1 = Parent A of expression 2)
- a section (or a full name) is a series of words, which are separated by spaces or dashes and correspond to the the first name and last name of a person
- we assume the maximum number of words in a section is 6 (your example has sections of 2 or 3 words, I assume we can have up to 6) 
  the sequence of words in a section matters (the section is always a first name followed by a last name and never the last name first, e.g. Jack John and John Jack are two different persons).
- there are 4 million expressions
- expressions are assumed to contain only English characters. Numbers, spaces, punctuation, dashes, and any non-English character can be ignored
- we assume the easy matches are already done (like the exact expression matches) and we do not have to search for exact matches

Technically the goal is to find series of matching expressions in the 4-million expressions list. Two expressions are considered matching expression if their Levenstein distance is less than 2.

Practically we create two lists, which are exact copies of the initial 4-million expressions list. We call then the Left list and the Right list. Each expression is assigned an expression id before duplicating the list.
Our goal is to find entries in the Right list which have a Levenstein distance of less than 2 to entries of the Left list, excluding the same entry (same expression id).

I suggest a two step approach to resolve the two challenges separately. The first step will reduce the list of the possible matching expressions, the second will simplify the Levenstein distance measurement since we only look at very close expressions. The technology used is any traditional database server because we need to index the data sets for performance.

**CHALLENGE A**

The challenge A consists of reducing the number of distance measurements. We start from a maximum of approx. 16 trillion (4 million to the power of two) and we should not exceed a few tens or hundreds of millions. 
The technique to use here consists of searching for at least one similar word in the complete expression. Depending on how the data is distributed, this will dramatically reduce the number of possible matching pairs. Alternatively, depending on the required accuracy of the result, we can also search for pairs with at least two similar words, or with at least half of similar words.

Technically I suggest to put the expression list in a table. Add an identity column to create a unique id per expression, and create 12 character columns. Then parse the expressions and put each word of each section in a separate column. This will look like (I have not represented all the 12 columns, but the idea is below):

```
|id | expression | sect_a_w_1 | sect_a_w_2 | sect_b_w_1 |sect_b_w_2 |
|1 | peter pan + marta steward | peter | pan | marta |steward      |
```

There are empty columns (since there are very few expressions with 12 words) but it does not matter.

Then we replicate the table and create an index on every sect... column. 
We run 12 joins which try to find similar words, something like

```
SELECT L.id, R.id 
FROM left table L JOIN right table T 
ON L.sect_a_w_1 = R.sect_a_w_1
AND L.id <> R.id
```

We collect the output in 12 temp tables and run an union query of the 12 tables to get a short list of all expressions which have a potential matching expressions with at least one identical word. This is the solution to our challenge A. We now have a short list of the most likely matching pairs. This list will contain millions of records (pairs of Left and Right entries), but not billions.

**CHALLENGE B**

The goal of challenge B is to process a simplified Levenstein distance in batch (instead of running it in a loop). 
First we should agree on what is a simplified Levenstein distance. 
First we agree that the levenstein distance of two expressions is the sum of the levenstein distance of all the words of the two expressions which have the same index. I mean the Levenstein distance of two expressions is the distance of their two first words, plus the distance of their two second words, etc. 
Secondly, we need to invent a simplified Levenstein distance. I suggest to use the n-gram approach with only grams of 2 characters which have an index absolute difference of less than 2 .

e.g. the distance between peter and pieter is calculated as below

```
Peter       
1 = pe          
2 = et          
3 = te          
4 = er
5 = r_           

Pieter
1 = pi
2 = ie
3 = et
4 = te
5 = er
6 = r_
```

Peter and Pieter have 4 common 2-grams with an index absolute difference of less than 2 'et','te','er','r_'. There are 6 possible 2-grams in the largest of the two words, the distance is then 6-4 = 2 - The Levenstein distance would also be 2 because there's one move of 'eter' and one letter insertion 'i'.

This is an approximation which will not work in all cases, but I think in our situation it will work very well. If we're not satisfied with the quality of the results we can try with 3-grams or 4-grams or allow a larger than 2 gram sequence difference. But the idea is to execute much fewer calculations per pair than in the traditional Levenstein algorithm.

Then we need to convert this into a technical solution. What I have done before is the following: 
First isolate the words: since we need only to measure the distance between words, and then sum these distances per expression, we can further reduce the number of calculations by running a distinct select on the list of words (we have already prepared the list of words in the previous section).

This approach requires a mapping table which keeps track of the expression id, the section id, the word id and the word sequence number for word, so that the original expression distance can be calculated at the end of the process.

We then have a new list which is much shorter, and contains a cross join of all words for which the 2-gram distance measure is relevant. 
Then we want to batch process this 2-gram distance measurement, and I suggest to do it in a SQL join. This requires a pre-processing step which consists of creating a new temporary table which stores every 2-gram in a separate row – and keeps track of the word Id, the word sequence and the section type

Technically this is done by slicing the list of words using a series (or a loop) of substring select, like this (assuming the word list tables - there are two copies, one Left and one Right - contain 2 columns word_id and word) :

```
INSERT INTO left_gram_table (word_id, gram_seq, gram)
SELECT word_id, 1 AS gram_seq, SUBSTRING(word,1,2) AS gram
FROM left_word_table
```

And then

```
INSERT INTO left_gram_table (word_id, gram_seq, gram)
SELECT word_id, 2 AS gram_seq, SUBSTRING(word,2,2) AS gram
FROM left_word_table
```

Etc.

Something which will make “steward” look like this (assume the word id is 152)

```
|  pk  | word_id | gram_seq | gram | 
|  1   |  152       |  1          | st |
|  2   |  152       |  2          | te |
|  3   |  152       |  3          |  ew |
|  4   |  152       |  4          |  wa |
|  5   |  152       |  5          |  ar |
|  6   |  152       |  6          |  rd |
|  7   |  152       |  7          |  d_ |
```

Don't forget to create an index on the word_id, the gram and the gram_seq columns, and the distance can be calculated with a join of the left and the right gram list, where the ON looks like

```
ON L.gram = R.gram 
AND ABS(L.gram_seq + R.gram_seq)< 2 
AND L.word_id <> R.word_id
```

The distance is the length of the longest of the two words minus the number of the matching grams. SQL is extremely fast to make such a query, and I think a simple computer with 8 gigs of RAM would easily do several hundred of million lines in a reasonable time frame.

And then it's only a matter of joining the mapping table to calculate the sum of  word to word distance in every expression, to get the total expression to expression distance.

Comment: By the way there's a solution to improve performance, if this is still too slow: replace the 2-grams by numbers - build a mapping table of all the possible 2-grams on the side. Since there is a small number of possible 2-grams (assuming we only work on 2-grams) the use of SMALLINT instead of CHAR(2) will dramatically improve the JOIN query performance. We only need to count the number of matching 2-grams, we don't need to know what letters they were made of originally.

Comment: FWIW 4^2 = 16 million (not trillion) pairwise comparisons is not the correct number. It should be 4*(4-1)/2 = 6 million comparisons. 4*(4-1) because no need for self comparison, and divide by two because the comparisons are (should be) unordered. Still quite a lot to do, but much less than 16.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the `stringdist` package anyway, does `stringdist::phonetic()` suit your needs? It computes the soundex code for each string, eg:

```
phonetic(pdata$parents_name)
[1] "P361" "P361" "A655" "J225"
```

Soundex is a tried-and-true method (almost 100 years old) for hashing names, and that means you don't need to compare every single pair of observations.

You might want to go further and do soundex on first name and last name seperately for father and mother.

Comment: Good idea, but my names are in Devnagari/Nepali, I believe soundex doesn't handle this too well

Comment: The general idea should work, you will just have to specify the vowels and consonants yourself.

Comment: Or you could try transliterating your data to english first, eg using https://github.com/prabhasp/Nepali-Language-Tools/blob/master/transliterate_ne2en.py as a preprocessing step.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is to use a data science approach to identify only similar (same cluster) names to compare using stringdist.

I have modified a little bit the code generating "parents_name" adding more variability in first and second names in a scenario close to reality.

```
num<-4e6
#Random length
random_l<-round(runif(num,min = 5, max=15),0)
#Random strings in the first and second name
parent_rand_first<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(num, random_l)
order<-sample(1:num, num, replace=F)
parent_rand_second<-parent_rand_first[order]
#Paste first and second name
parents_name<-paste(parent_rand_first," + ",parent_rand_second)
parents_name[1:10]
```

Here start the real analysis, first extract feature from the names such as global length, length of the first, length of the second one, numeber of vowels and consonansts in both first and second name (and any other of interest).

After that bind all these feature and clusterize the data.frame in a high number of clusters (eg. 1000)

```
features<-cbind(nchars,nchars_first,nchars_second,nvowels_first,nvowels_second,nconsonants_first,nconsonants_second)
n_clusters<-1000
clusters<-kmeans(features,centers = n_clusters)
```

Apply stringdistmatrix only inside each cluster (containing similar couple of names)

```
dist_matrix<-NULL
for(i in 1:n_clusters)
{
  cluster_i<-clusters$cluster==i

  parents_name<-as.character(parents_name[cluster_i])

  dist_matrix[[i]]<-stringdistmatrix(parents_name,parents_name,"lv")
}
```

In dist_matrix you have the distance beetwen each element in the cluster and you are able to assign the family_id using this distance.

To compute the distance in each cluster (in this example) the code takes approximately 1 sec (depending on the dimension of the cluster), in 15mins all the distances are computed.

**WARNING**: dist_matrix grow very fast, in your code is better if you will analyze it inside di for loop extracting famyli_id and then you can discard it.

Answer (score 2):

You may improve by not comparing all the couples of lines.
Instead, create a new variable that will be helpfull for decide if it is worth comparing.

For exemple, create a new variable "score" contaning the ordered list of letters used in parents_name (for exemple if "peter pan + marta steward" then the score will be "ademnprstw"), and calculate distance only between lines where score are matching.

Of course, you can find a score that fits better your need, and improve a little to enable comparison when not all the letters used are common ..

Comment: I like this approach, however I am lacking a good score that captures the most common differences. As I said, I already use differences in overall length and I started additionally using the first consonant (as the differences stem to a large extend from alternative spellings re the vowels). But this is slightly too restrictive. Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: Maybe two scores : one on consonants, one on vowels (with the same previous principle), and compare when at least one of the two matches.
And perhaps, just do this for the most used letters in you language (see letter frequency in wikipedia)

Comment: You can add a feature for each letter in the clustering phase counting the number of each letter in first and second name.

Comment: May be something like this :     `parents_name <- c("peter pan + marta steward",  "pieter pan + marta steward",    "armin dolgner + jane johanna dough",  "jack jackson + sombody else")
    alphagrep <- function (x)
    {
      res <- NULL
      for (i in letters)  {res <- c(res, grepl(i, x))}
      res
}

sum(alphagrep(parents_name[1]) + alphagrep(parents_name[2]) == 1)
sum(alphagrep(parents_name[1]) + alphagrep(parents_name[3]) == 1)
sum(alphagrep(parents_name[1]) + alphagrep(parents_name[4]) == 1)` and you compare when the sum is less than 1 or 2 or ... according to your need ..

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same performance issue couple years ago. I had to match people's duplicates based on their typed names. My dataset had 200k names and the matrix approach exploded. After searching for some day about a better method, the method I'm proposing here did the job for me in some minutes:

```
library(stringdist)

parents_name <- c("peter pan + marta steward",
            "pieter pan + marta steward",
            "armin dolgner + jane johanna dough", 
            "jack jackson + sombody else")

person_id <- 1:length(parents_name)

family_id <- vector("integer", length(parents_name))


#Looping through unassigned family ids
while(sum(family_id == 0) > 0){

  ids <- person_id[family_id == 0]

  dists <- stringdist(parents_name[family_id == 0][1], 
                      parents_name[family_id == 0], 
                      method = "lv")

  matches <- ids[dists <= 3]

  family_id[matches] <- max(family_id) + 1
}

result <- data.frame(person_id, parents_name, family_id)
```

That way the `while` will compare fewer matches on every iteration. From that, you might implement different performance boosters, like filtering the names with the same first letter before comparing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Making equivalency groups on non transitive relation does not make sense. If `A` is like `B` and `B` is like `C`, but `A` is not like `C`, how would you make families from that? Using something like soundex (that was idea of Neal Fultz, not mine) seems the only meaningful option and it solves your problem with performance too.

Comment: The transitivity is indeed an issue. However from a first inspection of the data it seems that the names are sufficiently different, so that if if A~=B and B~=C, treating as A~=C would still be ok. This can be handled in a single simple post-processing step

Answer (score 1):

What I have used to reduce the permutations involved in this sort of name matching, is create a function that counts the syllables in the name (surname) involved.  Then store this in the database, as a pre-processed value.  This becomes a **Syllable Hash** function.

Then you can choose to group words together with the same number of syllables as each other.  (Although I use algorithms that allow 1 or 2 syllables difference, which may be presented as legitimate spelling / typo errors...But my research has found that 95% of misspellings share the same number of syllables)

In this case `Peter` and `Pieter` would have the same syllable count (2), but `Jones` and `Smith` do not (they have 1).  (For example)

If your function does not get 1 syllable for `Jones`, then you may need to increase your tolerance to allow for at least 1 syllable difference in the Syllable Hash function grouping that you use. (To account for incorrect syllable function results, and to catch the matching surname correctly in the grouping)

My syllable counting function may not apply completely - as you might need to cope with non-English letter sets...(So I have not pasted the code...Its in C anyway)  Mind you - the Syllable count function does not have to be accurate in terms of TRUE syllable count; it simply needs to act as a reliable Hashing function - which it does.  Far superior to SoundEx which relies on the first letter being accurate.

Give it a go, you might be surprised how much improvement you get by implementing a Syllable Hash function.  You may have to ask SO for help getting the function into your language.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to compare every parent pair (every row in parent_name data frame) with all other pairs (rows), and keep rows that have Levenstein distance smaller or equal to 2.

I have written following code for the beginning:

```
pdata<-data.frame(parents_name=c("peter pan + marta steward",
                                 "pieter pan + marta steward",
                                 "armin dolgner + jane johanna dough",
                                 "jack jackson + sombody else"))

fuzzy_match <- list()
system.time(for (i in 1:nrow(pdata)){
  fuzzy_match[[i]] <- cbind(pdata, parents_name_2 = pdata[i,"parents_name"],
                            dist = as.integer(stringdist(pdata[i,"parents_name"], pdata$parents_name)))
  fuzzy_match[[i]] <- fuzzy_match[[i]][fuzzy_match[[i]]$dist <= 2,]
})
fuzzy_final <- do.call(rbind, fuzzy_match)
```

Does it return what you wanted?

Comment: It does (except is not in the format as specified in my questions, but nevermind). Your solution is however not efficient and will break down once a few million observations are used.

Comment: It is possible to make it faster using parallel computing (foreach loop). What does it mean that it breaks down?

Comment: With breaking down I mean it takes 100000 years do complete, you can use the second code I provided in my question to get a bigger data set, then you'll see that you code performs quite badly.

Answer (score 0):

it reproduces your output, i guess you will have to decide partial matching criteria, i kept the default agrep ones

```
pdata$parents_name<-as.character(pdata$parents_name)
x00<-unique(lapply(pdata$parents_name,function(x) agrep(x,pdata$parents_name)))
x=c()
for (i in 1:length(x00)){
  x=c(x,rep(i,length(x00[[i]])))
}
pdata$person_id=seq(1:nrow(pdata))
pdata$family_id=x
```