# How to find unique identifiers by fuzzy string variables

Tags: r

(apologies for poor phrasing of the title, I lack the proper vocabulary)

Consider the following data frame, where `id3` is what we want to create by considering only column `id1` and `id2`

```
df = data.frame(id1 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
            id2 = c('CompanyA Inc','CompanyA Inc.','CompanyA Inc','CompanyA Inc','ComapnyB','ComapnyB','NewNameB','ComapnyB'),
            id3 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

I want to create an identifier (`id3`) for each "company". `id2` is an "unclean" identifier (in the sense that names slightly change, but string cleaning is not an option).

```
df
   id1           id2 id3
1    1  CompanyA Inc   1
2    1 CompanyA Inc.   1
3    2  CompanyA Inc   1
4    2  CompanyA Inc   1
5    3      ComapnyB   2
6    3      ComapnyB   2
7    4      NewNameB   2
8    4      ComapnyB   2
```

I imagine one would need an algorithm which for a given `id1` value, checks all `id2` values and returns the `id1`'s that correspond and then assigns an id to this, but I fail to see how to do that properly...

Comment: Hi, yould you please show the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Something to get you started: `plot(hclust(stringdist::stringdistmatrix(df$id2, useNames = "strings")))`

Comment: Also look at `fuzzyjoin` (which uses `stringdist` too)

Comment: May be somme help here : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058104/efficient-string-similarity-grouping/48096986#48096986)