# R Find the "groups" of tuples

Tags: r

I try to find the "group" (`id3`) based on two variables (`id1`, `id2`):

```
df = data.frame(id1 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
            id2 = c('a','b','a','c','c','d','x','y','y','z'),
            id3 = c(rep('group1',6), rep('group2',4)))


   id1 id2      id3
1    1   a   group1
2    1   b   group1
3    2   a   group1
4    2   c   group1
5    3   c   group1
6    3   d   group1
7    4   x   group2
8    4   y   group2
9    5   y   group2
10   5   z   group2
```

For example  `id1=1` is related to `a` and `b` of `id2`. But `id1=2` is also related to `a` so both belong to one group (`id3=group1`). But since `id1=2` and `id1=3` share `id2=c`, also `id1=3` belongs to that group (`id3=1`). The values of the tuple `((1,2),('a','b','c'))` appear no where else, so no other row belongs to that group (which is labeled `group1` generically).

**If you need to take care of `NA`s, check this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67331014/r-find-groups-of-tupples-ignoring-nas)**

My idea was to create a table based on `id3` which would subsequently populated in a loop.

```
solution = data.frame(id3= c('group1', 'group2'),id1=NA, id2=NA)
group= 1 

for (step in c(1:1000)) { # run many steps to make sure to get all values
  solution$id1[group] = # populate  
  solution$id2[group] = # populate  

  if (fully populated) {
    group = group +1
  }}
```

I am struggling to see how to populate.

---

Disclaimer: I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691062/how-to-find-unique-identifiers-by-fuzzy-string-variables?noredirect=1#comment96170733_54691062), but using names in `id2` led a lot of people point me to fuzzy string procedures in R, which are not needed here, since there exist an exact solution. I also include all code I have tried since then in this post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can leverage on `igraph` to find the different clusters of networks

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, FALSE)
cg <- clusters(g)$membership
df$id3 <- cg[df$id1]
df
```

output:

```
   id1 id2 id3
1    1   a   1
2    1   b   1
3    2   a   1
4    2   c   1
5    3   c   1
6    3   d   1
7    4   x   2
8    4   y   2
9    5   y   2
10   5   z   2
```