# R: Replacing Strings with their Most Common Variant

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I'm looking to standardise a set of manually inputted strings, so that:

```
index   fruit
1   Apple Pie
2   Apple Pie.
3   Apple. Pie
4   Apple Pie
5   Pear
```

should look like:

```
index   fruit
1   Apple Pie
2   Apple Pie
3   Apple Pie
4   Apple Pie
5   Pear
```

For my use case, grouping them by [phonetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178729/5195054) sound is fine, but I'm missing the piece on how to replace the least common strings with the most common ones.

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(stringdist)

index <- seq(1,5,1)
fruit <- c("Apple Pie", "Apple Pie.", "Apple. Pie", "Apple Pie", "Pear")

df <- data.frame(index, fruit) %>%
  mutate(grouping = phonetic(fruit)) %>%
  add_count(fruit) %>%
  # Missing Code
  select(index, fruit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need `group_by` the grouping, then select the most frequent (Mode) item

```
df%>%mutate(grouping = phonetic(fruit))%>%
     group_by(grouping)%>%
     mutate(fruit = names(which.max(table(fruit))))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   grouping [2]
  index     fruit grouping
  <dbl>    <fctr>    <chr>
1     1 Apple Pie     A141
2     2 Apple Pie     A141
3     3 Apple Pie     A141
4     4 Apple Pie     A141
5     5      Pear     P600
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove` to remove the `.`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame(index, fruit) %>% 
    mutate(fruit = str_remove(fruit, "\\."))
# index     fruit
#1     1 Apple Pie
#2     2 Apple Pie
#3     3 Apple Pie
#4     4 Apple Pie
#5     5      Pear
```

---

If we need to use `phonetic` and find the most frequent value

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}


data.frame(index, fruit) %>%
   mutate(grouping = phonetic(fruit)) %>%
   group_by(grouping) %>% 
   mutate(fruit = Mode(fruit))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   grouping [2]
#  index fruit     grouping
#  <dbl> <fct>     <chr>   
#1     1 Apple Pie A141    
#2     2 Apple Pie A141    
#3     3 Apple Pie A141    
#4     4 Apple Pie A141    
#5     5 Pear      P600
```

Comment: Is there any flexibility benefit to creating the `Mode` function?

Comment: @rsylatian  It can be reused a s a block in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be:

```
fruit %>%
 enframe() %>%
 mutate(grouping = phonetic(fruit)) %>%
 add_count(value, grouping) %>%
 group_by(grouping) %>%
 mutate(value = value[match(max(n), n)]) %>%
 select(-n) %>%
 ungroup()

   name value     grouping
  <int> <chr>     <chr>   
1     1 Apple Pie A141    
2     2 Apple Pie A141    
3     3 Apple Pie A141    
4     4 Apple Pie A141    
5     5 Pear      P600
```